# What's special about border width of 0.015625px?

Tags: html, css, border

I was fooling around with CSS and found something curious.

I would like to preface with that I know that all this is undocumented, meaning undefined behavior, but I still want to understand a bit better how it works.

I have a CSS rule like this:

```
.foo {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 1;
}
```

I noticed that when I set border width to a very low number, it gets "rounded" to 0 (eg. there is no border rendered). I then tried to find where is the threshold for the width of the border to render on Google Chrome. I found out (via manual binary search) that the threshold is 0.015625, or 1/64. Eg.

```
.foo {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0.015625;
}
```

renders the border but

```
.foo {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0.015624;
}
```

does not, as demonstrated on the snippet (will probably work only on Chrome).

```css
.thin, .thick {
  border: solid black;
}
.thin {
  border-width:0.015624px
}
.thick {
  border-width:0.015625px
}
```

```html
<div class='thick'>
Border width 0.015625
</div>
<div class='thin'>
Border width 0.015624
</div>
```

What is going on under the hood here? Why 2^-6?

But it doesn't stop there. I tried to find the threshold with more precision. I got to number 0.015624999534338711824899004199096..., and gave up after assuming that it doesn't converge to a rational number. Could anyone make sense of that number? Why doesn't it just truncate at some point? How does computational precision work here?

On other browsers, of course, the threshold is different. Firefox has the threshold close to 1/120, and after getting more exact, it gets wild (as expected) with 0.00833333330228929...

Comment: That number (`1.015625` to be exact) seems to be equal to `0.000001` in binary, so that is probably the reason for that.